# Codename One multiline Picker?

Tags: codenameone

is there a way to display the selected text as multiline in a Picker component ?

The Picker component extends from Button and it doesn't seem to be a simple way to display the text as multiline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can clone the `Picker` class and call it something like `CustomPicker` that extends `SpanButton` instead of `Button`.

You only have to change `Button` to `SpanButton`.

SpanButton is a container that has TextArea in it to display multiline text.

Take note of `setUIID()` that behaves differently with `SpanButton` and applies the `uiid` to the container and not the text. Call `setTextUIID()` to apply `uiid` to text.

Although this will show the selected string as a multiline text, you shouldn't expect a multiline display of options in the Picker Dialog that popup. It is platform dependent and controlled natively.

Comment: Thanks. I was expecting to be a more reusable/cleaner way. But this can remain as a request for a future version for codenameone.

Comment: i have created custom picker and changed extension to SpanButton,but addActionListener is not working. Is there something I'm missing?